# ASP.NET scheduled jobs

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks

I want to send mails and SMSs in a scheduled time. I would prefer not using a Windows Service.

Is there any options to schedule a task in a custom time in ASP.Net?

Please suggest which is best way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243353/schedule-task-in-asp-net)

Comment: i think you should take a look of this first,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360595/asp-net-scheduled-tasks?rq=1

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1671597.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858512/c-sharp-console-app-to-send-email-at-scheduled-times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem once when my website was hosted on a Godaddy shared hosting. I wanted to run scheduled tasks for sending emails without any windows service.

Finally, I resolved the issue by the use of cache.

A cache item expires on a given time or duration. In ASP.NET, you can add entries in the Cache and set an absolute expiry date time, or you can set a duration after which the item is removed from the cache. You can do this by utilizing the following method of the Cache class.

```
    public void Insert ( System.String key , System.Object value , 
                     System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency dependencies , 
                     System.DateTime absoluteExpiration , 
                     System.TimeSpan slidingExpiration , 
                     System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority priority , 
                     System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback )
```

The onRemoveCallback is a delegate to a method which is called whenever a cache item expires. In that method, we can do anything we like. So, this is a good candidate for running code periodically, consistently without requiring any page visit.

This means, we can simulate a Windows Service utilizing Cache timeout.

You can find the entire details on the codeproject url http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc.

Answer (score 2):

What about a timer callback, set it up in Application_Start:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimerCallback callback = (x) => { YourFunction(); };
    int intervalInMS = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;  // every 2 hours. 
    timer = new Timer(callback, state: null, dueTime: intervalInMS, period: intervalInMS);
}
```

Comment: Won't work if no one is reloading the web page to trigger the code!

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/07/18/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)..

At startup (global.asx), add an item to the HttpRuntime.Cache with a fixed expiration.

When cache item expires, do your work, such as WebRequest or what have you.

Re-add the item to the cache with a fixed expiration.
The code is quite simple, really:

```
private static CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddTask("DoStuff", 60);
}

private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
{
    OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null, 
        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
}

public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest
    // re-add our task so it recurs
    AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));
}
```

Your "DoStuff" is the method that triggers your real work required to run.

It's that easy!

Comment: I set this up for daily tasks on my server. It works well, but I found it necessary to check that `r == CacheItemRemovedReason.Expired` before running my task. For some reason, the cache gets cleaned out about every hour on my server with a reason of `CacheItemRemovedReason.Removed`. In those cases I don't run the task, I just re-schedule it (in my case, for 3AM each day)

Comment: @jramm - good catch as that could be cases with cache changes in the browser. Afterall, this post is quite old now

Answer (score 1):

Quartz.Net (http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net) is a library that makes it easy to setup and manage jobs as a part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class to encapsulate this behavior for tasks on my web server. It's inspired by the answers here and on Jeff Atwood's blog post, but I figured I'd share it in case it's useful to anyone else.

This is configured to work for my local timezone (CST), but could be adapted to another timezone pretty easily.

### Schedule a Task in `Application_Start`

This example schedules the `TaskUpdateUserRoles.Task` method to be called each day at 3:00AM CST. Place it in the `Application_Start` method in your `Global.asax.cs` file.

```
ServerTask.CreateDaily("Update User Roles",
    TaskUpdateUserRoles.Task,
    DateTime.Parse("3:00 AM").TimeOfDay); //This should be the local time. CST in this case.
```

### ServerTask Class

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;

namespace MySite.Admin.Tasks
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Manages recurring tasks to run on the server.
    /// </summary>
    public class ServerTask
    {
        private string TaskName { get; set; }
        private TaskFrequency Frequency { get; set; }
        private TimeSpan Offset { get; set; }
        private Func<bool> TaskFunction { get; set; }
        private CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;
        private static readonly string TaskLogPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Admin/Logs/");

        private ServerTask(string name, TaskFrequency freq, TimeSpan offset, Func<bool> taskFunction)
        {
            TaskName = name;
            Frequency = freq;
            Offset = offset;
            TaskFunction = taskFunction;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a daily task that will run at the specified hour and minute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="taskName">The task name.</param>
        /// <param name="hourAndMinute">The hour and minute when the task should run (Central Standard Time).</param>
        public static ServerTask CreateDaily(string taskName, Func<bool> taskFunction, TimeSpan hourAndMinute)
        {
            ServerTask thisTask = new ServerTask(taskName, TaskFrequency.Daily, hourAndMinute, taskFunction);
            thisTask.QueueTask();
            return thisTask;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a weekly task that will run on the specified weekday, hour, and minute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="taskName">The task name.</param>
        /// <param name="weekday">The day of the week when the task should run.</param>
        /// <param name="hourAndMinute">The hour and minute when the task should run (Central Standard Time).</param>
        public static ServerTask CreateWeekly(string taskName, Func<bool> taskFunction, DayOfWeek weekday, TimeSpan hourAndMinute)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan((int)weekday, hourAndMinute.Hours, hourAndMinute.Minutes, 0);
            ServerTask thisTask = new ServerTask(taskName, TaskFrequency.Weekly, ts, taskFunction);
            thisTask.QueueTask();
            return thisTask;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a monthly task that will run on the specified day of the month, hour, and minute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="taskName">The task name.</param>
        /// <param name="dayOfTheMonth">The day of the month when the task should run.</param>
        /// <param name="hourAndMinute">The hour and minute when the task should run (Central Standard Time).</param>
        public static ServerTask CreateMonthly(string taskName, Func<bool> taskFunction, int dayOfTheMonth, TimeSpan hourAndMinute)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(dayOfTheMonth, hourAndMinute.Hours, hourAndMinute.Minutes, 0);
            ServerTask thisTask = new ServerTask(taskName, TaskFrequency.Monthly, ts, taskFunction);
            thisTask.QueueTask();
            return thisTask;
        }

        private enum TaskFrequency
        {
            Daily,
            Weekly,
            Monthly
        }

        private void QueueTask()
        {
            try
            {
                OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(RunTask);
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(TaskName, 1, null,
                    getNextTaskTime(), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                    CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void RunTask(string taskName, object o, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
        {
            //First, verify that the cache entry has expired. It turns out the server often removes our Cache
            //item even when it hasn't expired (generally about once per hour - there must be a server process
            //that cleans out the cache regularly). If that happens, just re-queue the task again.
            if (r == CacheItemRemovedReason.Expired)
            {
                try
                {
                    Exception taskException = null;
                    bool taskResult = false;

                    Stopwatch taskTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    try
                    {
                        taskResult = TaskFunction();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        taskException = e;
                    }
                    taskTimer.Stop();

                    //Write a log file entry each time this task runs in a monthly log file
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(TaskLogPath)))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(TaskLogPath));
                    }
                    DateTime taskTime = Data.DataHelper.ConvertUTCtoCST(DateTime.UtcNow);
                    string logFileName = string.Format("Tasks.{0}.log", taskTime.ToString("MM.yyyy"));
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(TaskLogPath, logFileName), true))
                    {
                        if (taskException == null)
                        {
                            string taskResultString = taskResult ? "and reported success" : "but did not report successful completion.";
                            sw.WriteLine("The task \"{0}\" ran at {1} {2}. Task runtime was {3} milliseconds.",
                                taskName, taskTime.ToString(), taskResultString, taskTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("Attempted to run the task \"{0}\" at {1}, but the task failed with the following error after {2} milliseconds: {3} [StackTrace: {4}]",
                                taskName, taskTime.ToString(), taskTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), taskException.Message, taskException.StackTrace);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }

            //queue this task to be called again
            QueueTask();
        }

        private DateTime getNextTaskTime()
        {
            if (Frequency == TaskFrequency.Monthly)
            {
                return getNextMonthlyTime();
            }
            else if (Frequency == TaskFrequency.Weekly)
            {
                return getNextWeeklyTime();
            }
            return getNextDailyTime();
        }

        private DateTime getNextDailyTime()
        {
            DateTime now = Data.DataHelper.ConvertUTCtoCST(DateTime.UtcNow);
            DateTime taskTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, Offset.Hours, Offset.Minutes, 0);
            taskTime = taskTime > now ? taskTime : taskTime.AddDays(1);
            taskTime = Data.DataHelper.ConvertCSTtoUTC(taskTime);
            return taskTime;
        }
        private DateTime getNextWeeklyTime()
        {
            DateTime now = Data.DataHelper.ConvertUTCtoCST(DateTime.UtcNow);
            DateTime taskTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, Offset.Hours, Offset.Minutes, 0);
            while ((int)taskTime.DayOfWeek != Offset.Days)
            {
                taskTime = taskTime.AddDays(1);
            }
            taskTime = taskTime > now ? taskTime : taskTime.AddDays(7);
            taskTime = Data.DataHelper.ConvertCSTtoUTC(taskTime);
            return taskTime;
        }
        private DateTime getNextMonthlyTime()
        {
            DateTime now = Data.DataHelper.ConvertUTCtoCST(DateTime.UtcNow);
            DateTime taskTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, Offset.Days, Offset.Hours, Offset.Minutes, 0);
            if (taskTime.Day < now.Day)
            {
                taskTime = taskTime.AddMonths(1);
            }
            else if (taskTime.Day == now.Day)
            {
                taskTime = taskTime > now ? taskTime : taskTime.AddMonths(1);
            }
            taskTime = Data.DataHelper.ConvertCSTtoUTC(taskTime);
            return taskTime;
        }

        private DateTime ConvertCSTtoUTC(DateTime cstTime)
        {
            try
            {
                TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
                DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(cstTime, cstZone);
                return utcTime;
            }
            catch { }
            return cstTime; //fallback to unconverted time
        }

        private DateTime ConvertUTCtoCST(DateTime utcTime)
        {
            try
            {
                TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
                DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, cstZone);
                return cstTime;
            }
            catch { }
            return utcTime; //fallback to unconverted time
        }
    }
}
```

### Signature of Task Method

```
public static class TaskUpdateUserRoles
{
    public static bool Task()
    {
        //perform task here. Return true if successful.
    }
}
```