# How do I set up a schedule task on my server?

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks

I have a shared host with ASP MVC, my worker process times out after 5 minutes causing site to take up to 30 seconds to restart. I can't edit these settings with shared hosting. I found some info online where I can use a schedule task that will keep hitting the site every few minutes keeping it from going idle.

> Executable    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>
> Argument  -c "(new-object
>   system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://[domain.tld][path][file_name]')"

1. Not sure about the Executable and the Argument? I not sure what to put there. Should I put the path to the home page? Or to a page with few views like the privacy page?
2. What's a good practice setup to keep site from going idle, with a schedule task?

Answer (score 0):

The executable & argument form the command that can be executed by a scheduler to make a request to a webpage and print out the data returned. For example, if you run this using the command line terminal (assuming you have `powershell`), you should see a whole bunch of javascript and html code present on google.com:

```
powershell -c "(new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('https://google.com')"
```

I am not sure whether or not this is an acceptable practice to keep websites from going idle on shared hosting spaces.

Comment: Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360595/asp-net-scheduled-tasks?rq=1